# Website translation architecture and implementation

Tags: asp.net, sql, architecture, translation

I'm conducting a project in which a website should have multi-language support.
Now, this website is supposed to serve about 500K+ visitors a day, so it must be super-efficient.

I've created a table of parameters {[ID],[Name]} AND a linkage-table {[objectID],[parameterID],[languageID],[value]}. I think it's the best way to deploy multi-language support while having the privilege to translate different parameters for each language.

As far as I know, server's memory is much faster than a physical HDD. Therefore, I'm planning to store ASP.NET Application State objects for my translation architecture.
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594.aspx)

How does my plan sound so far? any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, much appericiated!

I'm well aware of resource provider, yet I want to allow my client to easily add and modify these values, let alone add a new language/translation.

Is there any way of connecting resource provider to a generic MSSQL table?
Values will be written into the table and the provider shall load them into memory.
On an addition of a language, values will be reloaded.

Comment: Please just edit your question to provide additional information. Stack Overflow is not a forum, answers are reserved for information that solves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning on making an app that support multiple languages, your instant reflex should be let .net do the work for you. What i'm reading in your question is that you are setting up something to support that. You should know that localization is the way to go when you want to develop a multi-language environment.

Take a look at this [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9.aspx), it should give you a general idea on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

So, localizing an application can be divided into two parts:

- Localizing business logic entities.
- Localizing everything else.

In the question I see words which are related to business entity localization. For that purpose I agree with the concept to have separation between entities and their localizations.

**Part 1 - Localizing entities**:

Personally I do this way in database:

```
table Entity {EntityID, Name} -this is the entity-related table.
table EntityByLang {EntityID, LanguageID, Name} -this is the localized version of the table for each supported language.
```

This way allows me to have default values for each localizable property like `Name` and its localization, if such is available in the localized table. What's left here up to you is - you need to implement the data-access-layer which takes the `Name` localized for the current user language, or the default value (if language or the translation is not available for the given language).

**Part 2 - Localizing everything else**:

Here, with no alternatives in terms of the performance, I would recommend using some kind of static resources. Personally I live with static resources available for standard asp.net applications.

From the architectural point of view, don't directly refer to localization code from your UI code, like this (which I don't like):

```
var translation = HttpContext.Current.GetGlobalResourceObject("hello");
//excuse me, if I don't exactly remember the GetGlobalResourceObject() method name...
```

Instead, I would recommend using this kind of approach:

```
var translation = AppContext.GetLocalizationService().Translate("hello");
```

Where: `AppContext` - some kind of facade/factory (in fact, implementation of abstract facade/factory). `GetLocalizationService` - initially returns some kind of `ILocalizationService`, when implemented it returns `StaticResLocalizationService` (which implements `ILocalizationService`). This way allowing switching from one kind of localization to another. And particularly `StaticResLocalizationService` works with asp.net static resources

Sorry for messy sample codes, but I hope you understand my approach.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create custom resource provider, you can read more here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx

with this model you can leverage existing asp .net localization functionality